# How to read this functional code

Tags: functional-programming, miranda

Having trouble reading (interpreting) this functional Miranda code.

```
g = (foldr (+) 0) . (foldr ((:) . ((#) . (:[]))) [])
```

I know what it does

- Calculate the size of a list by taking the length via `#`
- Creating a one element list containing the above length of the original input list
- Collapsing the new list using `foldr` into a single integer with the operation `+0` on each element

However I am confused by the brackets and don't see where the input list is fed in. What does the rightmost `[]` constructor do?

Also why does this code only work via the function g, but if I call it directly it throws an error?

Comment: When you say "call it directly," what do you mean?

Comment: run the RHS in live editor rather than declaring g in the script editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, `g` is a function that returns the length of the list.

Let's break the function into some parts.

```
|| returns 1 for any input.
||   return_one "hoobar" = 1
return_one :: * -> num
return_one = (#) . (:[]) 

|| ignore first argument, insert 1 to the second argument.
||   insert_one "hoobar" [4,5,6] = [1,4,5,6]
insert_one :: *->[num]->[num]
insert_one = (:) . return_one

|| sum of list.
||   sum_list [7,8,9] = 24
sum_list :: [num] -> num 
sum_list = foldr (+) 0

|| generate list of 1 which as the same length of original list. 
||   change_one ["apple","banana"] = [1,1]
change_one :: [*] -> [num]
change_one = foldr insert_one []

|| return the length of the list.
||   g ["apple","banana"] = 2
g :: [*] -> num
g = sum_list . change_one
```

I would explain some confusing functions.

#### return_one

`(:[])` is a function that creates single element list, and `(#)` returns the length.
Strictly speaking, `(:[])` is `(:)` which takes `[]` as first argument.

therefore `(:[]) "hoobar" = "hoobar":[] = ["hoobar"]`, and applying `(#)` to it returns 1.

#### change_one

It starts with empty list `[]` and traverses through the list with inserting 1 to the front.

```
foldr insert_one [] ["apple","banana"]
= foldr insert_one [1] ["apple"]
= foldr insert_one [1,1] []
```

Comment: For return_one why is `:` needed? This is the appender, why isn't `[]` sufficient as an empty list constructor? Also why doesn't this function work in the live editor (`:[]`)?

Comment: I don't know what live editor means since I'm working in REPL, but have you tried evaluating `(:[]) 3` ?

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I was not reading the functions as prefix.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Miranda too well, but based on Haskell (I believe the differences between the two here would be minor, with only the `#` being a unary operator for list length being the only semi-significant one and with `||` being the comment syntax): The `.` is function composition:

```
(p . q) x = p (q x)
  || also can be written as:
p . q = \x -> p (q x)
```

Function composition is an associative operation, so `p . (q . r)` = `(p . q) . r` = `p . q . r`.

Using this information, we can expand this with the definition of `.`:

```
g      = (foldr (+) 0) . (foldr ((:) . ((#) . (:[]))) [])       || Original definition
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr ((:) . ((#) . (:[]))) [] list)
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x -> (:) (((#) . (:[])) x)) [] list)
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x -> (:) ((\y -> (#) ((:[]) y)) x)) [] list)
```

This can be cleaned up some more:

```
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x -> (:) ((\y -> (#)(y:[])) x)) [] list) || More conventional operator syntax for the innermost `:`
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x -> (:) ((#)(x:[]))) [] list)           || Innermost lambda was applied to x. Substitute y for x.
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x -> (:) ((#)([x]))) [] list)            || Apply innermost `:`
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x -> (:) #[x])) [] list)                 || Remove unnecessary parentheses
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x acc -> (:) (#[x]) acc) [] list)        || Explicitly write implicit argument. This particular step is called eta-expansion
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x acc -> (:) 1 acc) [] list)             || #[x] is always 1, no matter what x is
g list = foldr (+) 0 (foldr (\x acc -> 1 : acc) [] list)               || More conventional syntax for `:`
```

Also note that the `foldr` doesn't apply `+0` to every element, as you've stated in the question. `foldr op z (a:b:c:[])` becomes `op a (op b (op c z)))` (`a:b:c:[]` is another way to write `[a,b,c]`). I always thought this diagram is helpful to understand that:

[image: foldr diagram]

Additionally, most likely the reason that you got an error when calling it directly is that `p . q x` is *not* the same as `(p . q) x`.

Comment: Thanks, anyway to print/see the eval stack as the graph is computed?

Comment: @clicky I've never used Miranda, so I'm not sure. I suspect not since (I believe) Miranda has not been under active development in decades. But I'm not familiar with Miranda tools. There are a few Haskell tools at various stages of development along these lines though (which I haven't used), like [ghc-vis](http://felsin9.de/nnis/ghc-vis/).

Comment: @clicky (I also added a bit at the end about the last part of your question)